# Swapping branches on the remote

Tags: git, github

Just to make sure:

```
git branch -m test test-old
git push origin test-old
git push origin :test

git branch -m test_tmp test
git push origin test
git push origin :test_tmp
```

Are these operations fully safe? I rename branches locally, push them to the remote and remove the old ones. Won't I loose anything?

EDIT:

```
git checkout test
git branch -b test-old
git push origin test-old
git push origin :test

git checkout test_tmp
git branch -b test
git push origin test
git push origin :test_tmp
```

Comment: Afaik `git branch -m` changes the reflog too, so you lose the fact that there was an old branch. You could just create a new branch based on your old one with `git branch -b <newname>` and then push that.

Comment: So, something like in the edit?

Comment: Dang. I mistyped. `git checkout -b <branch>` makes a new branch (instead of `git branch -b`, but you also need a `git br -D test` to delete the `test` branch, otherwise the second `git co -b` doesn't work.